# Convert image file to Blob

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have the following code:

```
var file = document.getElementById("image1");
var filename = file.files[0].name;
//console.log("Archivo: " + filename);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child('imagenes/'+filename);

var reader = new FileReader();
var rawData;

reader.onload = function(e) {
    rawData = reader.result;   
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

ref.put(rawData).then(function(snapshot){

});
```

File -> get the data file input (an image).

And I want convert this file to blob in the moment that the form is send, to upload to firebase storage the image in the format BLOB, how I can do this?
I was used the fileReader, but always return the same error:

> 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

How do convert the file image to a blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply set `rawData` inside the onload function like you're doing. By the time `ref.put()` is run, the onload function will not have been called, so rawData will ALWAYS be undefined. `ref.put()` takes in the file as its parameter, so simply use `ref.put(file.files[0])` (No reader required):

```
var file = document.getElementById("image1");
var filename = file.files[0].name;
//console.log("Archivo: " + filename);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child('imagenes/'+filename);

ref.put(file.files[0]).then(...);
```

See also the very common: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Okay, but now, I have the next error: 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. On the last line.

Comment: @JuanmaPerez See my edit. `file` is an HTML Input field. You want to access `.files[0]` to grab the actual file.

Comment: Before do the changes, Firebase response with this error: Argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File. reader.result not is the blob?

Comment: What happens if you just use `ref.put(file.files[0])` instead of doing anything with the reader?

Comment: Okay, just solved the problem, and working correctly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @JuanmaPerez [This popped up a few days ago, just a heads up](https://medium.com/@scosta/why-firebase-sucks-ce5d2302eb20)